# Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

In my app I am calling logout api(post) and `AsyncStorage.clear();` then my login screen come but some how unable to store state.

[image: [this waring get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y386X.png)]

[this waring in device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RAAC.jpg)

I am also unable to click on login screen button and other component.

This is my slice.js

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import loginService from "../../services/userService";

export const logout = createAsyncThunk("logout", async (action) => {
  const response = await loginService.logout(action);
  return response.data;
});

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'userDetails',
  initialState: {
    loading: false,
    error: null,
    message: null,
    success: false,
    details: null,
    secret: null,
    authorizeSecret: null,
    isPwdReseted: false,
    deviceInfomation: {},
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(logout.pending, (state, action) => {
      state.loading = true;
      state.success = false;
    });
    builder.addCase(logout.fulfilled, async (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.success = action.payload.Success;
      state.message = action.payload.Message;
      if (action.payload.Success && action.payload.StatusCode === 200) {
        await AsyncStorage.clear();
        console.log('Storage Clear');
      }
    });
    builder.addCase(logout.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.success = false;
      state.error = action.payload
    });
  }
});
```

this is console log

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 2):
Error: Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path 'userDetails.loading'.  This may cause incorrect behavior. (https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-mutate-state)
Error: Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path 'userDetails.loading'.  This may cause incorrect behavior. (https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-mutate-state)
```

I know some how I didn't get initial state for my login screen, but why I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The `logout.fulfilled` reducer case function is declared `async` and so ***implicitly*** returns a Promise object instead of the next state.

```js
builder.addCase(
  logout.fulfilled,
  async (state, action) => { // <-- implicit Promise returned
    state.loading = false;
    state.success = action.payload.Success;
    state.message = action.payload.Message;
    if (action.payload.Success && action.payload.StatusCode === 200) {
      await AsyncStorage.clear();
      console.log('Storage Clear');
    }
  }
);
```

Redux reducer functions are to be ***pure, synchronous*** functions.

## Solution

Move the asynchronous "side-effect" of clearing the storage into the asynchronous action. Update the `logout.fulfilled` reducer function to be synchronous and only update the state.

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import loginService from '../../services/userService';

export const logout = createAsyncThunk(
  "logout",
  async (action) => {
    const response = await loginService.logout(action);

    if (response.Success && response.StatusCode === 200) {
      await AsyncStorage.clear();
      console.log('Storage Clear');
    }

    return response.data;
  }
);

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "userDetails",
  initialState: {
    ...
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(logout.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = true;
        state.success = false;
      });
      .addCase(logout.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.success = action.payload.Success;
        state.message = action.payload.Message;
      });
      .addCase(logout.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.success = false;
        state.error = action.payload
      });
  },
});
```